# Detect Browser Refresh to Prevent a Method from Triggering in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I have a Method that is setup to send out an email after the user reaches to this page. However, I want to prevent it from sending out again when the user accidentally refresh the page. Down below is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Session["ID"] = "50";
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["ID"] as string))
  {
    Response.Redirect("./default");
  }
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    email();
  }
}
```

I realized that refreshing the page isn't going to post back, it's more of a GET than a post.

Comment: Check this out at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379557(VS.80).aspx#bedrockas_topic2).

Comment: You can use hidden field to save value after first load and prevent it to send email again.